# Screen for RasPi - scavenging from useless "tablet"?

Tags: raspberry-pi, display, tft

I found an old WinCE machine with a completely useless platform - however the screen would be perfect for a Rapsberry project.

Problem is: the sticker either does not have the real model number or this is a completely unknown device - which is doubt. I'd expect this to be the most common - hence cheapest - part imaginable...

Sticker:

[image: Sticker on back of screen]

Connector to motherboard:

[image: Connector to motherboard]

- Is there any way to attach this to either HDMI or DSI easily and cost effectively?
- Would it be possible to tell/semi-reliably guess if it is

  - "Usual 40-pin LVDS"
  - "Usual 40-pin RGB TTL"
  - something else
- Any ideas where else could I find a product ID of some kind?

Comment: no .............

Comment: @jsotola I suspected this... But care to explain a bit? This seems to have 40 pins - but in absence of a spec sheet I can't tell if this is the "usual" 40 pin stuff which does have adapter boards available... Not exactly cheap per se...

Comment: `absence of a spec sheet` prevents the `easily and cost effectively`

Comment: What would be the usual 40-pin interface? We can't guess from the photo if that is an LVDS display interface or just logic level RGB. To find out, you must do the reverse engineering what kind of signals they are and how the data is sent. It might be easy to interface, after you spend hours reverse engineering it.

Comment: I think the best way to infer a pinout would be to chase out the signals from the connector to the chip that drives it and do some research on that chip

Comment: @Bryan I'll try this though everything is put under RF shielding. When I was tinkering around though, I noticed the the one holding this one is slightly loose.

Comment: @ppeterka - if the table is toast the shielding can be snipped away gently with good snips or the solder can be released with a good hot air gun - but dont overcook it or the part numbers will fade on the ic's beneath.